# Error 1822 al crear una llave foránea en mysql

Tags: mysql

gente.

Estoy haciendo el script de una base de datos en `MySQL`. Al momento de añadir una llave foránea a una tabla, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Error code: 1822 failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'carreras_plan_materia_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'carreras_plan'.
```

El error me da en esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE carreras_plan_materia(
clave_carrera VARCHAR(10),
clave_plan VARCHAR(10),
clave_materia VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (clave_carrera, clave_plan, clave_materia),
FOREIGN KEY (clave_carrera) REFERENCES carreras_plan(clave),
FOREIGN KEY (clave_plan) REFERENCES carreras_plan(plan), 
FOREIGN KEY (clave_materia) REFERENCES materias(clave));
```

La ejecución me falla al intentar:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (clave_plan) REFERENCES carreras_plan(plan),
```

Las tablas a las que se les hace referencia, son:

```
CREATE TABLE carreras (
clave VARCHAR(10),
nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (clave));

CREATE TABLE carreras_plan(
clave VARCHAR(10),
plan VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (clave, plan),
FOREIGN KEY (clave) REFERENCES carreras(clave));
```

Sin embargo, si la columna `clave_plan` le pongo referencia a la columna `clave` de la tabla `carreras_plan`, puedo añadir la llave foránea sin problemas:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (clave_plan) REFERENCES carreras_plan(clave),
```

El orden que tengo al crear las tablas es: `carreras`, `carreras_plan`, `carreras_plan_materia`.

No entiendo por qué sucede esto, si tanto las columnas `clave` y `plan` de la tabla son llaves primarias y poseen el mismo tipo de datos. ¿Podrían ayudarme a saber por qué sucede esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Da la impresión de que tiene un lío en tu diseño, como si faltara una tabla que se llame `plan` donde resida la llave primaria `plan`.

Answer (score 2):

Para que poder realizar la relación que quieres hacer en la tabla `carreras_plan_materia`:

> FOREIGN KEY (clave_plan) REFERENCES carreras_plan(plan)

Tienes que crear un índice al campo `plan` que quieres referenciar en la tabla `carreras_plan` de esta forma :

```
CREATE TABLE carreras_plan(
clave VARCHAR(10),
plan VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (clave, plan),
KEY idx_plan (plan),
FOREIGN KEY (clave) REFERENCES carreras(clave));
```

O si ya tienes creada la tabla, solo agrégalo:

```
ALTER TABLE carreras_plan
ADD INDEX idx_plan (plan ASC);
```

Y de esta forma ya no tendrás problemas para crear la tabla `carreras_plan_materia`.